# Create function for different normal distributions

Tags: anylogic

I want to use a function to assign different normal distributions for the waiting time in a queue based on a agent parameter.

[Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trmyk.png)

Fuction body:

```
if (agent.tar == "A03")
    return normal(4.70,16.38);
if (agent.tar == "A02")
    return normal(4.70,16.38);
else normal(4.8,16.9);
```

Does anyone know what "Type" i have to use to return it to the queue?

[Queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejLDp.png)

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Brgds Kev

The pictures above shows my approach. I just need to know what type should be returned.

Comment: Do not add your code as images, add the code as text instead.

Comment: It is actually useful to see the full screenshot as AnyLogic properties convey important content beyond the raw code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "delay time" field wants to know a `double` so your function MUST return a "double" value.

Just choose that in the "Returns value" dropdown for "Type", it is the 2nd entry from the top.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it works. Actually, I already tried that but as you can see I forgot the "return" after "else".

Comment: yes, Java is very particular in forcing you to really return something :)